# Get value from one to many relationship. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, one-to-many

I have two models Vehicles and Image,
Vehicle hasMany images

```
public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');
}
```

Image belongsTo a Vehicle:

```
public function vehicle(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\vehicle');
}
```

I've retrieved vehicles like:
In Controller:

```
$ads=ads::orderBy('views','desc')->get();
foreach ($ads as $ad) {
    $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ad->Vehicleid)->get()->toArray();
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)
     @foreach($popularvehicle as $vehicle)
      {{$vehicle['vname']}}
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Now, I want to retrieve an image that belongs to $vehicle.
I've tried following syntax:

```
@foreach($popularvehicles as $popularvehicle)
     @foreach($popularvehicle as $vehicle)
          @foreach($vehicle->image as $image)
             <a href="page-product-details.html">
             <img src="{{ asset("images/$image->title") }}" alt="{{ $image->title }}" >
             </a>
          @endforeach
     @endforeach
@endforeach
```

But it is throwing an exception of: Trying to get property of non-object.
What can I do to make it right?

Comment: have a look at this.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/requests/laravel-issue-in-getting-the-value-of-one-to-many-relationship

Comment: $popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ad->Vehicleid)->with('images')->get()->toArray();

Comment: Try $vehicle->images as $image ?

Comment: @AkkapongKajornwongwattana Method ‌​toArray does not exist.

Comment: @LordMarty Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::image()

Comment: getting the ads and using it's id to get array of arrays looks inefficient. try set up relation between ads and vehicles and use eager loading will loads everything you require. sathi, pahila ko question ma maile diyeko ansewer solution matra ho tarika ramro haina.

Comment: Ads ra vehicle bich one to one relation pani xa.
`public function vehicle(){
  return $this->belongsTo('App\vehicles');
 }`
`public function ads(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\ads');
}`

Comment: `echo $ads=ads::with('vehicle.images)->all();` loads you all required data. see eager loading in doc. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: I used `$ads=ads::with('vehicle.images')->get();` It is returning null on vehicles. Result: `[{"id":2,"status":"Active","views":149,"created_at":"2017-01-13 09:07:55","updated_at":"2017-01-24 06:30:24","Vehicleid":16,"vehicle":null}`

Comment: I figured it out, i didn't used naming convention. So after overriding the foreign key value, i have now value of vehicles too. thank you sanzeeb.

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple example: 
You have a model, the model has details in another model.

```
class Vehicle extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'brand',
        'etc',
    ];

    public function details()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\VehicleDetails');
    }
}
```

And the details model:

```
class VehicleDetails extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'color',
        'engine',
    ];

    public function vehicle() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Vehicle');
    }

}
```

I usually use transformers to return the needed data, but you don't have to. To make use of the hasMany you can call it like this:

```
return Vehicle::find($vehicleId); // Retrieve the vehicles from the server
// the object retrieved has the details.
$vehicle->details; // then you can use contains the details

   // example:
    @foreach($vehicle->details as $details)
      <a href="page-product-details.html">
        <img src="{{ asset("images/$details->imagetitle") }}"
          alt="{{ $details->title }}" >
      </a>
    @endforeach
```

The returned object contains the details and you can loop trough it how ever you want. 
Without more details about how you retrieve the data I can't be more specific.

Comment: Actually i tried `$popularvehicles=vehicles::find($ad->Vehicleid); I've got multiple ad i had to run it in the loop. And it stored only last returned data. So i had to put it in an array. Now, i dont know how to retrieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I can see 2 problems;
**Your popularvehicles is an array of arrays**

```
$popularvehicles[]=vehicles::where('id',$ad->Vehicleid)->get()->toArray();
```

The toArray is turning everything into an array. You no longer have Vehicle objects. https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray

Use ->all() instead.

**Second Problem**

```
@foreach($vehicle->image as $image)
```

You want to use $vehicle->image**s**

Comment: If i use all() how can i filter vehicles with ads??

Comment: You could do something like;


`$ads = Ads::orderBy('views','desc')->get(); // Gets all the ads`
`$vechicles = Vehicle::whereIn('id', $ads->pluck('vehcile_id'))->get();`

That should give you all the vechicles without doing N+1 queries.
There are other queries you could do as well, Laravel has a powerful query builder

Comment: Or instead of `vehicles::where('id',$ad->Vehicleid)->get()->toArray();` you could just do `Vehicles::find($ad->Vehicleid);` No need to all() or toArray() as you are just retreiving the one vehicle per add.

Comment: Do you have Vehicle setup as a relationship on the Ad? If so you should just be able to do `$ad->vehicle`

Comment: yes i do.In Ads `public function vehicle(){ return $this->belongsTo('App\vehicles'); }  In Vehicle public function ads(){ return $this->hasOne('App\ads'); }`

Comment: When i did, `$ads=ads::orderBy('views','desc')->get();
      foreach ($ads as $ad) {
        # code...
         $vs=vehicles::find($ad->Vehicleid);
      }
     return $vs;` It is only returning last value.

Comment: You'll need to do `$vs[]=vehicles::find($ad->Vehicleid);` if you want $vs to be an array